# C# Safely using LINQ across threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, thread-safety

I have a program that is constantly reading and parsing a large stream of data from a WebSocket. All of the parsing happens on one thread within the client, and the data is organized into a `SortedSet<T>` tree for fast operation.

All of the data is added, updated, and removed without a hitch.

The problem comes when I try to access the data from another thread. It will run fine, but somewhere along the lines is a race condition that will be hit within a minute or two.

Consider this code (running on its own thread) to update the UI in near real-time:

```
private async Task RenderOrderBook()
{
    var book = _client.OrderBook;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var asks = book.Asks.OrderBy(i => i.Price).Take(5).OrderByDescending(i => i.Price);
            var bids = book.Bids.OrderByDescending(i => i.Price).Take(5);

            orderBookView.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                ...omitted due to irrelevance
            }));

            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The race condition lies within the LINQ operations on `book`. The common error is that `i.Price` (a `decimal` variable), or perhaps just the object `i` is referring to, is null. Additionally, my shoddy attempt to just swallow the exception does not actually work.

Regardless, my guess is that the data is being parsed and manipulated so fast that eventually, when using the LINQ OrderBy operation, it will hit a case where a node has been removed by the client, attempt to read from it, and throw an exception.

The `book.Asks` and `book.Bids` properties were initially of type `SortedSet<T>` and pointed directly to the data member itself. In an attempt to mitigate this race condition scenario, I attempted to change them to an array of the node, and use a `_asks.ToArray()` call to essentially make a copy to read from. This helped make the problem occur a bit less frequently, but nonetheless it still does happen.

How can I make this thread-safe?

**Additional Code Snippets**

```
public PriceNode[] Asks
{
    get { return _asks.ToArray(); }
}

public PriceNode[] Bids
{
    get { return _bids.ToArray(); }
}
```

Comment: using thread-safe collections like `ConcurrentDictionary`, or immutable collections as in the System.Immutable nuget package will likely get you 90% of the way there.

Comment: There is nothing in the code that you've shown that has any problem with threading or race conditions. The only spot that there might be a problem is in the `...omitted due to irrelevance` code. Is it possible to show that code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first rule of UI development is that you never perform I/O on the UI thread.  Sounds like you've got that one covered.

My second rule is that once something is visible to the UI thread, you can't touch it from any other thread.  There is exactly **one** exception to this rule, and that is for immutable data: if an object *will not change*, then any thread can touch it.  Mutable data?  **No touch.**  Keep in mind that "mutable data" includes most collections.

Your life will be *so much easier* if you can follow these two rules.  Following one without breaking the other can be tricky, but there are ways to do it, and once you have a decent grip of them, you'll be in a better place.  The path to enlightenment begins here:

Your read thread (the thread reading off the socket) is allowed to create all the new objects it wants, but it can't update existing objects.  It also can't modify any collections that the UI thread is using.  If you're only adding new objects, this isn't so bad: your read thread can pull data off the socket and use it to cook up new objects.  When those objects are ready, it has to hand them over to the UI thread, and the UI thread can add them to the relevant collections.  The bulk of the work (and all of the I/O) happens on the read thread, which is what we want, per Strobel's Rule #1.  The act of "committing" the already-populated objects should be trivial by comparison.  Per Rule #2, once any mutable objects get handed off to the UI thread, your read thread can't touch them again.  Ever.

Updating existing objects is trickier.  There's a couple ways you can approach this.  One is to have the read thread use the latest data to create new objects, which it then hands off to the UI thread.  If you have *very* simple object graphs, the easiest option might be to simply replace the old objects with their newer versions, keeping in mind that any UI code referencing an old object will need to know that it's been replaced.  Alternatively, the UI thread can use the data from the new object to update the existing object.  If you're following Rule #2, this will be totally thread-safe, and any UI code that pointed to the old object automatically sees the new data without any torn reads or other race-related nastiness.  This approach is *probably* your best bet.

If, after trying out the approaches in the previous paragraph, you find that you are generating unacceptable amounts of garbage, there is a third option.  The read thread can copy the raw data for each object into a temporary buffer, then hand the buffers over to the UI thread, which can use the data in the buffers to update the existing objects.  This means more work occurring on the UI thread, but at least the data is already in memory (the socket I/O is already done).  Since the point of this approach is to create less garbage, it only makes sense if you *reuse* the buffers.  That means you need a thread-safe buffer pool.  The read thread acquires a temporary buffer, fills it from the socket, hands it to the UI thread, which returns it to the pool when it's done.  Astute readers will note that passing mutable buffers between threads bumps up against Rule #2, so take care that once a thread hands over a buffer, it immediately forgets about it.  Because this approach requires a stronger grasp of thread safety to make the pool work, I recommend it only as a last resort.  If you can get away with one of the options in the previous paragraph, please do so.

Regardless of which approach you use for updating existing objects, you'll need a way to match up the new objects/data with the old objects.  If each object has a unique identifier, you can use a `Dictionary<,>` as an efficient lookup mechanism.  Replacing old objects with their newer copies is a bit more involved, because the old versions may be scattered across multiple collections, some of which may not support efficient replacement.

One last thing: when you hand over new/updated objects to the UI thread, it is vastly preferable to do it **in batches**.  For example, you're better off posting a single operation to your UI thread to update 100 objects than posting 100 separate operations that each update one object.